# Load image in HTML quickly

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, load

I have a image of 1 MB and I  want to put on background.
I see that the image take too much time to load. 
What can I do to have this image in my background but to load quickly?
The image is .PNG.

Comment: You can change the file extension to reduce the file size. `.PNG` is generally larger than, say, `.jpg`. What is your current file extension?

Comment: Use photosop and lower the quality but keep image dimension.

Comment: You can use the hyper-web, it's even faster than the regular web.

Comment: @TylerH: Usually I work with png files.

Answer (score 2):

Optimize the image. You can use [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com/), [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)...etc.

Take a look [here](http://jamiemason.github.io/ImageOptim-CLI/).